# Add rows in a html file from an external php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to find how to insert a row line to a table in html so , but i would like to do it using an external php file, but maybe another solution because the purpose is to get a table from a database one and write it down to an html table.

i've tried to look on the internet but i didn't find something that was fitting with what i was lookin for.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.  Your question is a difficult to understand and you have not provided any examples of what you have tried, what the output was and how this is different what what you had expected.

Comment: i haven't tried something that has given me a result, but the question is if exist a way to write down a database table in html table. I'm new on these things i've just started programming in html and php sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean some thing like "example 1" from here (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)?

You only need to add the html tags to create the html table (table, td, ...).

EDIT:

This example includes the html tags and should do what you want:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<?php

   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");

   $query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID DESC LIMIT 50,5";

   if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

       echo "<table>";
       /* fetch associative array */
       while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['CountryCode'] . "</td></tr>";
       }
       echo "</table>";

       /* free result set */
       $result->free();
   }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to write down the essential parts as a short conclusion and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or is no longer reachable.

Comment: yes but how can i share those data to an external html file in this way i'll get just the data from the database

Comment: I added the complete example with html tags.

Comment: it returns to me this error :    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /Library/WebServer/Documents/serverConnectionAndStore/phps/getElement.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Library/WebServer/Documents/serverConnectionAndStore/phps/getElement.php on line 8 .

Comment: You need to initial $mysqli. I will add it.

Comment: oh yes i did it but i need to use the data inside the html code so not just to display the table i would like to have something like this. `<html> <head></head><body><table> <tr> " data obtained from database" </tr></table></body `

Comment: I edit my answer. I prefer separating html and php but this should do it.

Comment: maybe we misunderstood each other but i would like to separate html and php so maybe what i'm wondering is impossibile or not logical i would like to share those data using some trick i'don't know maybe passing them to a js file and than by the js putting them in the html file using something like https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp